# .scrollTop() works ONLY with webkit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, webkit

apparently .scrollTop() works only in webkit browsers... is this possible? that's very strange because i found some questions here in stackoverflow titled "scrollTop works only in Firefox" but what is happening to me it's different

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($('body').scrollTop())
})
```

even if i replace `window` with `document` nothing changes. the funny thing is when i run this function and i scroll down the page the value still 0 BUT the red little badge beside the number 0 changes at every pixel scrolled...

In chrome and opera this works perfectly.

i'm running Firefox 34.0 on Win7x64 and i'm using jquery 2.1.3

Comment: try `$('html, body').scrollTop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because WebKit sets the scrollTop for the main document on the `body`, while other browser use the `html` element. However, you can just use `window` instead of `'body'` or `'html'` to get the main document scroll position.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop())
});
```

BTW, calling jQuery on an object isn't the fasting thing in the world, and scroll events can fire very rapidly. Consider caching `$(window)` in a variable for improved performance.

```
var $window = $(window);
$window.scroll(function() {
    console.log($window.scrollTop())
});
```

Comment: Why not use `this` in your first example.

Comment: @self You could use `this`, there's no read difference, other than one is smaller, and the other *might* GZIP better. The second one is the one that really should be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you need scrolltop position, i prefer use offset:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {console.log($('body').offset().top) })
```